# Aurelia bindingEngine.propertyObserver - Detect when property changes due to object change

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

We are using a similar code to detect changes to a specific object property.

```
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-framework';

class MyViewModel {
    static inject = [BindingEngine];

    constructor(bindingEngine) {
        this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
        this.myObject = {observeMe : 'Test' + new Date()};
    }

    attached() {
        this.subscription = this.bindingEngine
            .propertyObserver(this.myObject, 'observeMe')
            .subscribe((newValue, oldValue) => { 
                this.objectValueChanged(newValue, oldValue) 
            });

        setInterval(() => {
            this.myObject.observeMe = 'Test' + new Date();
        }, 2000);
    }

    detached() {
        this.subscription.dispose();
    }

    objectValueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(`observeMe value changed from: ${oldValue} to:${newValue}`);
    }
}
```

https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/how-to-observe-objects-in-aurelia-using-the-binding-engine/23

The above example works fine and `objectValueChanged` is triggered when the property `observeMe` on `this.myObject` is changed. However due to some circumstances we would sometimes like to replace the entire object but still fire an event. Example:

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.myObject = { observeMe : 'Test' + new Date()}
    //Object.assign does not work either
    //this.myObject = Object.assign({ observeMe : 'Test' + new Date()}, this.myObject);
}, 2000);
```

This does not trigger `objectValueChanged`. What could we do instead if we need to catch both property changes or if the entire object is changed?

Right now we have solved it by not creating new objects but instead replace values like this. However it would be a lot easier for us if we could track that the object was changed as well.

```
Object.keys(this.myObject).forEach((key) => {
    this.myObject[key] = newMyObject[key];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expressionObserver` on `BindingEngine` to observe a long path with many accessors. Sandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/x3qz6w2k6w

Basically binding engine gives a shortcut to do it that reads like the following:

```
bindingEngine.createObserverFor(someObject, 'at.this.property.path');
```

The value will be the value of final property in the path, and it's guarded against `null` / `undefined` by default so you will get `undefined` if any of property access along the path returns `null` / `undefined`